# What is cross-browser rendering?

Tags: html, css, browser

What is cross-browser rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How well does your HTML & CSS display in the various browsers or how compatible is your HTML & CSS in the various browsers.  Also includes your client scripts as mentioned below in the wikipedia quote.

Here's a link on sites that can help test your site's cross browser rendering:

http://freelancefolder.com/7-fresh-and-simple-ways-to-test-cross-browser-compatibility/

Comment: ahh, all the cross broswer/platform differences...I try to see it as a positive thing.  Just think of all all the work that developers have gotten out of competing companies' refusal to do things the same way.  $$$

Answer (score 4):

> Cross-browser refers to the ability
>   for a website, web application, HTML
>   construct or client-side script to
>   support all the web browsers. The term
>   cross-browser is often confused with
>   multi-browser. Multi-browser means
>   something works with several web
>   browsers. Cross-browser means
>   something works with all versions of
>   all browsers to have existed since the
>   web began.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-browser

Answer (score 0):

In plain English, websites are not displayed the same way in different browsers (even in the same browser type, but different version). The ability of the code written to build a website to make it look the same in all borwsers(although a very difficult task, and sometimes not achievable at all if using CSS3, IE won't render it unless it's IE9) is called cross-browsing.

Answer (score 0):

Every browser displays the same site differently - actually, even different versions of browsers can display the same site differently. It's all from the default styles set for elements in each browser, variance in support for the newer techniques (e.g. CSS3, HTML5, etc), and other factors (e.g. PNG transparency in IE6).

Here's some further reading to clear it up:
http://www.changry.com/design/9-cross-browser-compatibility-tools-for-designers-and-coders/