# Search bar in navbar doesn't look the same in Google Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have the following code for my search bar in the navbar. It looks well in Firefox but on Google Chrome the search bar stretches and goes below the navigation. How do I fix this?

```
    <div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class = "navbar-inner">
            <div class = "container">
                <a href = "#" class = "navbar-brand">SIG Inventory System</a>
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type='button' class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
                        <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                    <ul class = "nav navbar-nav ">
                        <li class = "active"><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">About</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm " placeholder="Search..." name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                    <!--<form class="nav navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                      <div class="form-group ">
                        <input class="form-control input-sm " placeholder="Search..." type="text">
                      </div>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                        <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
                      </button>
                    </form>-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: elements looking different in other browsers usually tend to involve a style sheet, so some CSS would be nice :)

Comment: You can read more about cross-browser rendering issues [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050443/what-is-cross-browser-rendering)

Comment: the CSS I used is bootstrap.css.. I didnt have any overrides on their styles.. that's why I was wondering why they are showing differently on different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in bootstrap 3, with very similar markup. Try adding this to your override `CSS`, it will fix the end issue but doesn't solve the actual problem, unfortunately. I haven't gotten that far, yet.

```
nav .navbar-form {max-width: 300px}
```

**Edit**

Apparently this is a little more elegant of a fix.

```
.navbar-form .input-group-btn,
.navbar-form .input-group-addon {
    width: auto;
}
```

However, I settled on:

```
.navbar-form .input-group-btn,
.navbar-form input { width: auto; }
```

See https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9950